# How mock specific function without affecting others in same one ES6 class?

Tags: mocking, jestjs

Here's my project:

MockTestDependency.js:

```
export default class MockTestDependency {
    testAction1() {
        return 'testAction1'
    }

    testAction2() {
        return 'testAction2'
    }
}
```

MockTest.test.js:

```
jest.mock('./MockTestDependency')

import MockTestDependency from './MockTestDependency'

beforeAll(() => {
    MockTestDependency.mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                testAction1: () => {return 'mocked1'},
            }
        }
    )
})

describe('mock test 3', () => {
    it('first case', () => {
        let mockTestDependency = new MockTestDependency()
        expect(mockTestDependency.testAction1()).toBe('mocked1')
        expect(mockTestDependency.testAction2()).toBe('testAction2')
    })
})
```

An error occurred after run `jest` command:

`TypeError: mockTestDependency.testAction2 is not a function`

So, how mock function `testAction1` without affecting function `testAction2`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jest.genMockFromMidule()

Comment: genMockFromMidule works, but I choosed jest.spyOn function finally, still thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `jest.spyOn()` function, it allows to mock only chosen method. When you use `jest.mock('./MockTestDependency')` it mocks all methods in module to `jest.fn()`

```
import MockTestDependency from './MockTestDependency'

beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(MockTestDependency, 'testAction1').mockImplementation(() => 'mocked1');
})

describe('mock test 3', () => {
    it('first case', () => {
        let mockTestDependency = new MockTestDependency()
        expect(mockTestDependency.testAction1()).toBe('mocked1')
        expect(mockTestDependency.testAction2()).toBe('testAction2')
    })
})
```